# Phonegap Assistance

Tags: android, jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I have the following scenario below: Please guide me.

I already have an existing web application develop using PHP & MySql, It works perfectly on 
on a normal browser. What I would like to do is have the very same functionality, on 
my "Android App" "iOS" and "BB".

I have been going through multiple forums, and I am still very confused. Here are my reasons:

1. I do not just want to load the app in the "WebView".
2. I want to be able to log in to my web app through phonegap, (need to send the credentials to the web app)
3. After logging in I want to be able to format the generated .html (to display on mobile)
4. On my browser it allows me to upload content to the server, if possible I would like to this as well:)

I already have the latest version of PhoneGap + ADT & SDK + Eclipse, I can develop static html apps
without any hassles, now, I just need to have client side html that talks to my server side php.

Something similar to the Facebook app and the Facebook Mobile Version.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Your question may be a bit to broad, you could try splitting it into different scenarios and explain what you have tried.

Comment: My Web App here http://bulltank.com > I would like to build client side .html .js .css pages and scripts that will talk directly to my PHP scripts,I want to be able to fetch this data (generated by php)dynamically,and will then format the returned data using CSS and display it on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I have just completed a project using PhoneGap, [Backbone JS](http://backbonejs.org) and [Require JS](http://requirejs.org), these acted as my MVC for the front end application which sent ajax request to my back end PHP application, which was converted into a rest API. [Laravel](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785) does this quite well, but it might have to be a custom build for you if you are already relying on a bespoke PHP build.

I was able to deploy to Android and iOS. However, using PhoneGap means that your application will be loaded in a WebView, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) might help exaplain a WebView in more detail.

Comment: Hi Ian, Thank you for the answer, Can you please see my below edit and advise.My Web App here bulltank.com > I would like to build client side .html .js .css pages and scripts that will talk directly to my PHP scripts,I want to be able to fetch this data (generated by php)dynamically,and will then format the returned data using CSS and display it on my app.

Comment: You want to have a look into jQuery and ajax. That will allow you to execute server side scripts via Javascript.